# WinAppDriver WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> url problems

Tags: winappdriver

I have got a solution, it's actually a demo on how Win App Driver should work but I can't for the life of me get it to work. Using Win App Driver with selenium and appium web drivers (as mentioned at 5 minutes into [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/UI-Tests-for-Desktop-and-UWP-Apps#c636759055350948681)). I have the solution as shown below and when I run my AddAlarm test I get the error ... "the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4723".

The full error message is at the bottom of this post.

My question is, what do I need to do to make the application we're testing "Alarm & Clock" actually launch on the url 127.0.0.1:4723 is there anything I have to do to make it available on that url / port? Also, how do I verify is "app"  and "Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" are correct in the setup?

```
//Class with my test "AddAlarm"
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System;

namespace AlarmClockTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ScenarioAlarm : AutoTest_SynTQ.UnitTestSession
    {
        private const string NewAlarmName = "Sample Test Alarm";

        [TestMethod]
        public void AlarmAdd()
        {
            // Navigate to New Alarm page
            session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AddAlarmButton").Click();

            // Set alarm name
            session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AlarmNameTextBox").Clear();
            session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AlarmNameTextBox").SendKeys(NewAlarmName);

            // Set alarm hour
            WindowsElement hourSelector = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("HourLoopingSelector");
            hourSelector.FindElementByName("3").Click();
            Assert.AreEqual("3", hourSelector.Text);

            // Set alarm minute
            WindowsElement minuteSelector = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("MinuteLoopingSelector");
            minuteSelector.FindElementByName("55").Click();
            Assert.AreEqual("55", minuteSelector.Text);

            // Save the newly configured alarm
            session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AlarmSaveButton").Click();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            // Verify that a new alarm entry is created with the given hour, minute, and name
            WindowsElement alarmEntry = session.FindElementByXPath($"//ListItem[starts-with(@Name, \"{NewAlarmName}\")]");
            Assert.IsNotNull(alarmEntry);
            Assert.IsTrue(alarmEntry.Text.Contains("3"));
            Assert.IsTrue(alarmEntry.Text.Contains("55"));
            Assert.IsTrue(alarmEntry.Text.Contains(NewAlarmName));

            // Verify that the alarm is active and deactivate it
            WindowsElement alarmEntryToggleSwitch = alarmEntry.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AlarmToggleSwitch") as WindowsElement;
            Assert.IsTrue(alarmEntryToggleSwitch.Selected);
            alarmEntryToggleSwitch.Click();
            Assert.IsFalse(alarmEntryToggleSwitch.Selected);
        }


        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
        {
            Setup(context);
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanup()
        {
            // Try to delete any alarm entry that may have been created
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var alarmEntry = session.FindElementByXPath($"//ListItem[starts-with(@Name, \"{NewAlarmName}\")]");
                    session.Mouse.ContextClick(alarmEntry.Coordinates);
                    session.FindElementByName("Delete").Click();
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            TearDown();
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public override void TestInit()
        {
            // Invoke base class test initialization to ensure that the app is in the main page
            base.TestInit();

            // Navigate to Alarm tab
            session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AlarmPivotItem").Click();
        }
    }
}




//Inherited class below
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace AutoTest_SynTQ
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTestSession
    {
        private const string WindowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";
        private const string AlarmClockAppId = "Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";

        protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;
        protected static RemoteTouchScreen touchScreen;

        public static void Setup(TestContext context)
        {
            // Launch Alarms & Clock application if it is not yet launched
            if (session == null || touchScreen == null)
            {
                TearDown();

                // Create a new session to bring up the Alarms & Clock application
                DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", AlarmClockAppId);
                session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities);
                Assert.IsNotNull(session);
                Assert.IsNotNull(session.SessionId);

                // Set implicit timeout to 1.5 seconds to make element search to retry every 500 ms for at most three times
                session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));

                // Initialize touch screen object
                touchScreen = new RemoteTouchScreen(session);
                Assert.IsNotNull(touchScreen);
            }
        }

        public static void TearDown()
        {
            // Cleanup RemoteTouchScreen object if initialized
            touchScreen = null;

            // Close the application and delete the session
            if (session != null)
            {
                session.Quit();
                session = null;
            }
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public virtual void TestInit()
        {
            WindowsElement alarmTabElement = null;

            // Attempt to go back to the main page in case Alarms & Clock app is started in EditAlarm view
            try
            {
                alarmTabElement = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AlarmPivotItem");
            }
            catch
            {
                // Click back button if application is in a nested page such as New Alarm or New Timer
                session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Back").Click();
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                alarmTabElement = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AlarmPivotItem");
            }

            // Verify that the app is in the main view showing alarmTabElement
            Assert.IsNotNull(alarmTabElement);
            Assert.IsTrue(alarmTabElement.Displayed);
        }
    }
}
```

Test Name:  AlarmAdd
Test FullName:  AlarmClockTest.ScenarioAlarm.AlarmAdd
Test Source:    C:\Users\ECombe.OPTIDOORS\Documents\SynTQCodedUITesting\AutoTest_SynTQ\SCN_Alarm.cs : line 30
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00

Result StackTrace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows.WindowsDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at AutoTest_SynTQ.UnitTestSession.Setup(TestContext context) in C:\Users\ECombe.OPTIDOORS\Documents\SynTQCodedUITesting\AutoTest_SynTQ\UnitTestSession.cs:line 28
   at AlarmClockTest.ScenarioAlarm.ClassInitialize(TestContext context) in C:\Users\ECombe.OPTIDOORS\Documents\SynTQCodedUITesting\AutoTest_SynTQ\SCN_Alarm.cs:line 71
Result Message: 
Class Initialization method AlarmClockTest.ScenarioAlarm.ClassInitialize threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4723
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters).

Comment: I think my actual problem is that WinAppDriver keeps exiting suddenly. I have described that problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007142/why-does-winappdriver-exe-close-immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was to use Developer mode. The actual problem was winappdriver.exe closing immediately. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007142/why-does-winappdriver-exe-close-immediately).